# Why can't I SSH to this AWS NAT instance in a public subnet?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-vpc

For experimentation purposes, I’m trying to setup an AWS EC2 inside a VPC that has both public and private subnets as described in [**this**](https://cloudpages.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/ssh-to-an-instance-in-private-subnet/) tutorial.

However, when I try to SSH in step #2, it fails (Operation times out. Connection failure):

```
$ ssh -i MyKeyFile.pem ec2-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out
```

and

```
$ telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 22
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
telnet: connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Why cannot I connect to this NAT EC2 as described in the tutorial? It seems like it should be simple

Comment: Check your firewall rules. Disable them temporarily and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Yes. The problem was that there was no inbound SSH route on the NAT's security group. Adding one allowed me to SSH successfully. The tutorial I followed omitted this crucial step.